# Glycerin yield upon saponification of beeswax

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I am making a custom grease (castor oil & sodium stearate) that will be suspended in beeswax. I have found that saponifying some beeswax for use in the grease results in higher operating temperatures after the grease is melted with the wax. I cannot have any glycerin in the final product, so I do not yet know how to properly make my own soap [at home].

The first reason I cannot have any glycerin, is because this will be used as a bullet lubricant for cast lead bullet, and I am concerned that the glycerin may form acrolein in the final application. The second reason is because the hygroscopic properties of glycerin are also bad. For more information, look up [Felix World Famous Lube](http://www.castpics.net/subsite/Lube/Felix.html).

As far as I can tell, there are no glycerides in beeswax but I cannot find data on this topic. If there are no glycerides in bees wax, then I do not believe it is possible to yield glycerin in the saponification process of only beeswax.

I am considering a trans-esterifcation process, just to remove any possible glycerin, but I may need butanol (due to the high saponification temperature of beeswax) which is expensive to the point that I would rather do something entirely different. I may be able to use ethanol if I slowly titrate the ethoxide into the molten beeswax. I also have many open questions here, since bees wax is more than just fatty acids.

So, does beeswax contain any glycerides?

Comment: It appears that there are no triglycerides in beeswax  http://www.pharmacy180.com/article/beeswax-302/     https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304012435_Beeswax_Production_Properties_Composition_Control